# Wordpress Customize the Custom articles page

Tags: wordpress

I want to developp a special section with particular type of contents.
I would like to have a dedicated page to submit a film.

I try with the custom page of wordpress but I would like to add obligatory custom field like :

- date
- type of movie
- ...

How could I do to make these field visible and block the submition if there are not field out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do :

Basically you need two steps to add a Custom Field to a Custom Post Type:

Create a metabox which holds your Custom Field
Save your Custom Field to the database

These steps are globally described here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-it-possible-to-add-an-extra-field-to-a-custom-post-type